# Python float numbers lose accuracy out of a tuple?

Tags: python, floating-accuracy

This next behaviour befuddles me, any explanation would be appreciated.

```
>>> a = (0.1457164443693023, False)
>>> print a
(0.1457164443693023, False)
>>> print a[0]
0.145716444369
```

Using python 2.7

Comment: That's not really the same question, there it's two different numbers, here it is on and the same. Also in my case both times it is printed and not converted to and from string and float.

Comment: `print x` is basically equivalent to `sys.stdout.write(str(x))`.  When you do `str()` on a tuple, the elements of the tuple are returned as their `repr`.  If they used `str`, it would be confusing to get `(1,)` for both `print ('1',)` and `print (1,)`.

Comment: FYI, this behavior is changed in Python 3 where the *str* and *repr* are both at full precision.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only difference is the `print`. The number doesn't change, just its representation. You can reduce your problem to:

```
>>> 0.1457164443693023
0.1457164443693023
>>> print 0.1457164443693023
0.145716444369
```

(I guess (and this is only and merely a guess) this boils down to `__repr__` vs `__str__` or something along this line)

Comment: hmm, it is indeed that in this case a[0].__str__() gives the shorter number and a[0].__repr__() give the longer one. I guess printing a float uses str while printing a tupple uses repr. Thanks.

Comment: @Eran print on a tuple also uses `str()`, but `str()` is called on the tuple.  A tuple's string representation uses `repr()` on the elements of the tuple itself.

Answer (score 6):

The first calls __ repr __ , the second __ str __

```
a = (0.1457164443693023, False)
print a
>>> (0.1457164443693023, False)
print a[0]
>>> 0.145716444369

print repr(a[0])
>>> 0.1457164443693023
print str(a[0])
>>> 0.145716444369
```

For some design reason Double.__ str __() returns fewer decimals.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like python does not print the full accuracy of a float, but it is still there.

```
>>> a = (0.1457164443693023, False)

>>> print a
(0.1457164443693023, False)

>>> print repr(a[0])
0.1457164443693023
```